# Please I need a JavaScript code that can edit mp3 URL

Tags: javascript

I need a JavaScript code that will  able me edit mp3 songs from it formal URL to another URL check http://mp3.bhojpuriyasongs.com and see what I mean thanks

Comment: What do you wants? Edit `MP3` or `URL`? What effort have you done? Even me will vote your question down.

Edit & you will get help...

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML could be something like this:

```
<audio id="audio-player" src="name_of_the_file.mp3" type="audio/mp3"></audio>
<button id"switch">switch</button>
```

Your javascript function could be something like this:

```
function changeAudioURL(player, newURL){
   player.pause();
   player.src = newURL;
   player.play();
}
```

You can call this function with a click event or what you need. An example:

```
var myPlayer = document.getElementById("audio-player");
var mySwicth = document.getElementById("switch");
mySwitch.onclick = function(){ 
   changeAudioURL(myPlayer, 'name_of_new_file.mp3');
};
```